# How do I query an n:n relationship from MS Dynamics CRM via SOAP?

Tags: php, soap, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365

I need to add some linked entities to a SOAP query on a Dynamics 365 CRM (the version it reports is `Version 1612 (8.2.1.176) (DB 8.2.1.176)`). The client implementation is in PHP.

With some trial and error and a lot of examples, I have been able to put together something like the following request body. (I'm not sure if this is the best way to structure a query; there seem to be several others including `<fetch>`, but this one has worked so far.)

```
<Execute xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services" xmlns:si="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <request xmlns:c="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts" si:type="c:RetrieveMultipleRequest">
    <c:Parameters xmlns:c2="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic">
      <c:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
        <c2:key>Query</c2:key>
        <c2:value si:type="c:QueryExpression">
          <c:ColumnSet>
            <c:AllColumns>true</c:AllColumns>
            <c:Columns/>
          </c:ColumnSet>
          <c:EntityName>entity1</c:EntityName>
          <c:LinkEntities>
            <c:LinkEntity>
              <c:LinkFromAttributeName>entity2id</c:LinkFromAttributeName>
              <c:LinkFromEntityName>entity1</c:LinkFromEntityName>
              <c:LinkToAttributeName>entity2id</c:LinkToAttributeName>
              <c:LinkToEntityName>entity2</c:LinkToEntityName>
              <c:JoinOperator>Inner</c:JoinOperator>
              <c:LinkEntities>
                <c:LinkEntity>
                  <c:LinkFromAttributeName>entity3id</c:LinkFromAttributeName>
                  <c:LinkFromEntityName>entity2</c:LinkFromEntityName>
                  <c:LinkToAttributeName>entity3id</c:LinkToAttributeName>
                  <c:LinkToEntityName>entity3</c:LinkToEntityName>
                  <c:JoinOperator>Inner</c:JoinOperator>
                </c:LinkEntity>
              </c:LinkEntities>
            </c:LinkEntity>
          </c:LinkEntities>
          <c:Orders>
            <c:OrderExpression>
              <c:AttributeName>name</c:AttributeName>
              <c:OrderType>Ascending</c:OrderType>
            </c:OrderExpression>
          </c:Orders>
          <c:PageInfo>
            <c:Count>1</c:Count>
            <c:PageNumber>1</c:PageNumber>
          </c:PageInfo>
        </c2:value>
      </c:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
    </c:Parameters>
    <c:RequestName>RetrieveMultiple</c:RequestName>
  </request>
</Execute>
```

(In this case, the relationship seems to be 1:n from entity1 to entity2, and n:1 from entity2 to entity3. In effect, entity2 contains only the foreign keys for joining entity1 and entity3, with some extra attributes.)

This query is apparently executed correctly (it runs without error, and it limits the result set according to the inner join), but I only get back columns from the first entity type.

How do I actually get the attributes of the joined entities?

Edit:

I have tried adding each of the following to the `<c:LinkEntity>` element:

```
<c:ColumnSet>
  <c:AllColumns>true</c:AllColumns>
</c:ColumnSet>

<c:Columns>
  <c:AllColumns>true</c:AllColumns>
</c:Columns>

<c:Columns>
  <a:string xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
    attribute1
  </a:string>
</c:Columns>

<c:ColumnSet>
  <c:Columns>
    <a:string xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
      attribute1
    </a:string>
  </c:Columns>
</c:ColumnSet>
```

Unfortunately, while none of these have caused an error, they also haven't changed the output.

Comment: Did you try adding  <c:ColumnSet>
            <c:AllColumns>true</c:AllColumns>
          </c:ColumnSet> inside <c:LinkEntities>
                <c:LinkEntity> ?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately that does not seem to make any difference in the response.

Comment: Sorry, instead of ColumnSet use Columns like this <c:Columns> <c:AllColumns>true</c:AllColumns> </c:Columns> inside <c:LinkEntities> <c:LinkEntity>

Comment: Still didn't work... until I shifted it around to put the Columns element first, before all the other children! (Oh, Microsoft...) Thanks very much! Please post a full answer so I can accept it. :D

Comment: Pleasure to help. Just verify if I placed it right, if not feel free to edit it. Btw, try latest techniques like fetchxml or crm web api - soap is far behind. I dint remember even :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placing the `Columns` element like below worked.

```
<Execute xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services" xmlns:si="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <request xmlns:c="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts" si:type="c:RetrieveMultipleRequest">
    <c:Parameters xmlns:c2="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic">
      <c:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
        <c2:key>Query</c2:key>
        <c2:value si:type="c:QueryExpression">
          <c:ColumnSet>
            <c:AllColumns>true</c:AllColumns>
            <c:Columns/>
          </c:ColumnSet>
          <c:EntityName>entity1</c:EntityName>
          <c:LinkEntities>
             <c:LinkEntity>

              <c:Columns>
                <c:AllColumns>true</c:AllColumns>
              </c:Columns>

              <c:LinkFromAttributeName>entity2id</c:LinkFromAttributeName>
              <c:LinkFromEntityName>entity1</c:LinkFromEntityName>
              <c:LinkToAttributeName>entity2id</c:LinkToAttributeName>
              <c:LinkToEntityName>entity2</c:LinkToEntityName>
              <c:JoinOperator>Inner</c:JoinOperator>
              <c:LinkEntities>
                <c:LinkEntity>
                  <c:LinkFromAttributeName>entity3id</c:LinkFromAttributeName>
                  <c:LinkFromEntityName>entity2</c:LinkFromEntityName>
                  <c:LinkToAttributeName>entity3id</c:LinkToAttributeName>
                  <c:LinkToEntityName>entity3</c:LinkToEntityName>
                  <c:JoinOperator>Inner</c:JoinOperator>
                </c:LinkEntity>
              </c:LinkEntities>
            </c:LinkEntity>
          </c:LinkEntities>
          <c:Orders>
            <c:OrderExpression>
              <c:AttributeName>name</c:AttributeName>
              <c:OrderType>Ascending</c:OrderType>
            </c:OrderExpression>
          </c:Orders>
          <c:PageInfo>
            <c:Count>1</c:Count>
            <c:PageNumber>1</c:PageNumber>
          </c:PageInfo>
        </c2:value>
      </c:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
    </c:Parameters>
    <c:RequestName>RetrieveMultiple</c:RequestName>
  </request>
</Execute>
```

Comment: Almost - it was in fact the first child inside the LinkEntity just as you said before.